# What is the next prime with this form?

Tags: prime-numbers

The following are primes,

$$P_1 = 2^2 + 3^3$$

$$P_2 = 2^2 + 3^3 +5^5 + 7^7$$

After these two, the only prime of such form I've found is,

$$P_3 = 2^2 + 3^3 + 5^5 + 7^7 + 11^{11} + 13^{13} +\dots+  83^{83} + 89^{89}$$

*Is there a prime number with this form after these three?* (I've checked prime numbers up to 5500, but I couldn't find any others.)

Comment: The [Alpertron](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM) confirms that $P_3$ is indeed prime. There is a hit in the OEIS, so the question is essentially looking for the prime entries of [A061789](https://oeis.org/A061789)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII, Okay thanks ( :

Comment: @quid, But my searching area is greater than Her. (5500 vs 1009)

Comment: This is not of crucial relevance in my opinion. What type of answer do you expect that could not be given to the other question?